# Java GUI element design

Tags: java, user-interface, swing, awt

I want to have custom design for buttons, lists and every element of GUI.

I can see Swing, AWT and other are providing some default design.

How can I customize it? Can I customize Swing elements? Any tutorial, documentation?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

[Look and Feel](http://download.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/lookandfeel/plaf.html) (Java's tutorial linked) is probably what you mean.

You can use one of the look and feels provided by Java, and if you have to create your own, there's a tutorial here: http://today.java.net/article/2006/09/11/how-write-custom-look-and-feel (but it's quite difficult).

Comment: Also check out alternate PLAFS like JGoodies (http://www.jgoodies.com/freeware/looksdemo/index.html), Substance (https://substance.dev.java.net/) etc.